# R - Calculating a Running Total Between Different Time Intervals

Tags: r

I have a data frame keeping track of some loan balances. Everytime a payment is made towards the balance ("Amount"), the new balance of that property's loan is displayed in the Balance column.

```
df = data.frame(Date = c("2015-03-01", "2015-05-01", "2016-07-02", "2017-11-24", "2017-12-15"),
            Property = c("1 Main St", "1 Main St", "1 Main St", "5 Main St", "1 Main St"),
            Amount = c(50000, -10000, -5000, 75000, -4000),
            Balance = c(50000, 40000, 35000, 75000, 31000)
            )
```

As you can see, the dates are fairly scattered and most months don't have any transactions to record. I'd like to be able to make a data frame that has the balance of each property at the beginning of each month, regardless of whether there was a transaction that month or not. Something like this:

```
Month = c("March 2015", "April 2015", "May 2015", "June 2015"),
Property = c("1 Main St", "1 Main St", "1 Main St", "1 Main St").
Balance = c(50000, 50000, 40000, 40000)
```

It also needs to be able to take the last transaction of the month (in the event there is more than one transaction for a property in a given month). Any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your `Date` field is of type "date". Here is the call I used to play with your data:

```
df = data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2015-03-01", "2015-05-01", "2016-07-02", "2017-11-24", "2017-12-15"), "%Y-%m-%d"),
            Property = c("1 Main St", "1 Main St", "1 Main St", "5 Main St", "1 Main St"),
            Amount = c(50000, -10000, -5000, 75000, -4000),
            Balance = c(50000, 40000, 35000, 75000, 31000),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
            )
```

Notice, I also added the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument to the `data.frame` call.

Then, I used the following code to maybe(?) answer your question:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

arrange(df, Date)

from <- first(df$Date)
to <- last(df$Date)

new_df <- df %>%
        complete(Date = seq.Date(from, to, "day"))%>%
        fill(Property:Balance)%>%
        group_by(year = year(Date), month=month(Date, label = TRUE), Property)%>%
        summarise(Balance = last(Balance))
```

Comment: It's working for the property that starts at the "from" date. However, the second property only gets NAs as balances, even after it's loan was initialized. Any idea why?

Comment: **Nevermind, I figured out why. The first and last were taking the first and last row (I assumed it was taking the min/max values). My DF wasn't sorted, so once I sorted it, it was fine. Thanks very much for your help!**

Comment: @D.Bryant, I edited the answer by including `arrange()` in order to sort `df` before taking the first and last values. If I answered your question, feel free to check the check mark so others can see the question has an answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks again for answering my questions.